# How to set up CORB log to debug XQUery information

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I am using CORB to run module on MarkLogic DB via command:

> ml local corb --modules=abcd.xqy

And want to generate log on this processing for which I have added `xdmp:log()` into `abcd.xqy`. But, I am unable to find out where is generated log message. It is not on command prompt and not in MarkLgoic log directory.

Is there any way to setup CORB log setting through properties file? If yes, how? or any other way to track generated log message.

**Some background of the follow is:**

1. I have ingested RDFXML through roxy command

> ml local deploy content
>
> Now, I am taking RDFXML as input and converting them into triples through above mentioned CORB command. It is running successfully.
>
> insert-taxonomy-triples.xqy has some log messages which are not displaying on command prompt as well as MarkLogic log directory.
>
> **My complete command is:**
>
> ml local corb --modules=/tools/ingest/insert-taxonomy-triples.xqy --uris=/tools/ingest/find-taxonomy-uris.xqy

**insert-taxonomy-triples.xqy**

> import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
>   import module namespace c = "http://bsigroup.com/ns/meddev/common/constants" at "/app/common/constants.xqy";
>
> declare namespace xdmp = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp";
>
> declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
>
> let $taxonomy-name := fn:replace(fn:replace($URI, '/taxonomies/',''), '.rdf','')
>
> let $graph-name := fn:concat($c:BSI-TAXONOMY-BASE-URI, $taxonomy-name)
>
> let $log := xdmp:log("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
>
> let $log := xdmp:log(fn:concat("/tools/ingest/insert-taxonomy-triples.xqy ", 
>                                  "main module: parsing taxonomy ", $URI, 
>                                  " and inserting triples to graph ", $graph-name), 
>                        "debug")
>
> let $permissions := (xdmp:permission("meddev-role", "update"), xdmp:permission("meddev-role", "read"))
>
> return sem:rdf-insert(
>            sem:rdf-parse(fn:doc($URI), "rdfxml"),
>            (fn:concat("override-graph=", $graph-name)),
>            $permissions,
>            ($graph-name)
>          )

**find-taxonomy-uris.xqy**

> declare namespace xdmp = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp";
>   declare namespace cts  = "http://marklogic.com/cts";
>
> let $taxonomy-uris := cts:uri-match("/taxonomies/*")
>
> let $log := xdmp:log(fn:concat('/tools/ingest/find-taxonomy-uris.xqy',
>                    'main module: the taxonomies found are ',
>                    fn:count($taxonomy-uris),
>                    ' URIs '
>                    ),
>                 'debug')
>
> return (
>      fn:count($taxonomy-uris),
>      $taxonomy-uris
>   )

**Command prompt result:**

> D:\mdol-dev\mdol-as>ml local corb --modules=/tools/ingest/insert-taxonomy-triple
>   s.xqy --uris=/tools/ingest/find-taxonomy-uris.xqy
>
> java -cp D:/mdol-dev/mdol-as/deploy/lib/java/corb.jar;D:/mdol-dev/mdol-as/deploy
>   /lib/java/marklogic-xcc-5.0.2.jar com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager xcc://adm
>   in:admin@localhost:9002/meddev-content "" tools/ingest/insert-taxonomy-triples.x
>   qy 1 tools/ingest/find-taxonomy-uris.xqy "/" meddev-modules false
>
> logging to CONSOLE Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.SimpleLogger configureLogger
>
> INFO: setting up logging for: com.marklogic.ps
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager run
>
> INFO: com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager starting: version 2010-08-24.1 on 1.7
>   .0_40 (Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment)
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager run
>
> INFO: maximum heap size = 1783 MiB
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager prepareContentSour
>   ce
>
> INFO: using content source xcc://admin:admin@localhost:9002/meddev-content
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager registerStatusInfo
>
> INFO: Configured modules db: meddev-modules
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager registerStatusInfo
>
> INFO: Configured modules root: /
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager registerStatusInfo
>
> INFO: Configured uri module: tools/ingest/find-taxonomy-uris.xqy
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager registerStatusInfo
>
> INFO: Configured process module: tools/ingest/insert-taxonomy-triples.xqy
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager prepareModules
>
> INFO: checking modules, database: meddev-modules
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager prepareModules
>
> INFO: Skipping module installation: tools/ingest/find-taxonomy-uris.xqy
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager prepareModules
>
> INFO: Skipping module installation: tools/ingest/insert-taxonomy-triples.xqy
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager populateQueue
>
> INFO: populating queue
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager populateQueue
>
> INFO: invoking module /tools/ingest/find-taxonomy-uris.xqy
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager populateQueue
>
> INFO: expecting total 2
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager populateQueue
>
> INFO: queued 2/2
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:35:59 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Monitor monitorResults
>
> INFO: monitoring 2 tasks
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:39:29 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Monitor showProgress
>
> INFO: completed 1/2, 0 tps, 1 active threads
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:39:29 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Monitor monitorResults
>
> INFO: waiting for pool to terminate
>   Jul 16, 2014 10:39:29 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Monitor monitorResults
>
> INFO: completed all tasks 2/2, 0 tps, 0 active threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any messages generated by `xdmp:log()` will be in `ErrorLog.txt` (on Linux: `/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog.txt`). The command as you have it written is also using the [Roxy Deployer](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy).

The `--modules` parameter tells Corb what you want to do, but you also need to specify either `--collection` (a string naming a collection to process) or `--uris` (a module that will identify which documents to process). Add one of those to your command, and you should see Corb's logging messages appear on the console.

---

Based on the additional information, I see a couple of things.

1. find-taxonomy-uris.xqy apparently found two: `INFO: queued 2/2`.
2. insert-taxonomy-triples.xqy processed those two successfully: `INFO: completed all tasks 2/2`.
3. You have three `xdmp:log()` calls, two of which pass in the "debug" parameter. The default setting for file log level is info, which would exclude the debug messages. In the Admin UI, go to Groups -> Default (assuming that's the group name you're using), scroll down to "file log level" and set it to "debug". That should make those messages appear. You should already be seeing the `xdmp:log("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")` call; are you?

Another observation: since your goal is to transform RDFXML to MarkLogic triples, you could use [mlcp](http://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp), which performs that transformation for you out of the box. If you tried that and it didn't work, that would be useful to know.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right, it is using Roxy. I am also using --uris as parameter like "ml local corb --modules=abcd.xqy --uris=xyz.xqy". But still log is not available anywhere.

Comment: Could you please post the command you're running and whatever the response is on the console? I've never seen it not give any response (I'm one of the Roxy maintainers).

Comment: Thanks Dave. I have updated my question to give some more details. Please have a look and suggest accordingly.